# Does Maxwell's electromagentic light wave have breadth in the direction it is traveling or does just the very tip exist?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light

Maxwell's light waves are drawn as that sine wave of electric field and magnetic field at right angles.  They usually draw 2 or three full waves in science book diagrams. But how much of it exists at one instant?  If it were the equivalent of one photon (or one quanta of energy) is there one full wave or is there just the tip of the wave?  I.e. Does the wave equivalent of 1 photon of green light have a length equal to its wavelength of 550nm?  Or does it have no length and at any given time it's just two perpendicular line segments?

What I'm wondering is the following. There are many explanations of why light has no way of existing without moving. Is this another way of explaining why light must be moving to exist? It only has a third dimension by moving along that axis?  It would only have 2 dimensions if it weren't moving?

(I get that if I jerked a jump rope then I'd see an entire wave travel on thru. But without a medium it seems like it could be different.)

Comment: Maxwell didn’t know about photons. They had not been experimentally detected, and they are nowhere to be found in his classical field theory.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to talk about the volume of a photon, it doesn't have a breadth or a length. This is non-intuitive as there is no human scale equivalent. When my favourite radio station transmits the photons have a wavelength in the order of 100m, this is nothing to do with the length of the photon just it's frequency, it's still best thought of as a point particle in that its energy will arrive instantaneously.

Comment: @mattfitzgerald It seems to me that if you thought of a photon as a point particle then you wouldn't be able to comprehend its polarization. That's why I asked if it's 2D, like 2 small perpendicular line segments.

Comment: @G. Smith, yes good point.  I changed the text to read "Maxwell light wave".  Nonetheless do you know the answer?  Is light 2D but traveling in its 3rd D?

Comment: You changed *one* occurrence of “photon” to “light wave”. There are six others, including in the title and tags. A light wave is three-dimensional. I think of photons as zero-dimensional (i.e., point particles).

Comment: OK I thought that in wave-land a photon can be thought of as an electromagnetic wave (Maxwell's model) of exactly one quanta of energy, but maybe people only say photon in particle-land.  I'll change tit.  Nonetheless if we're talking about wave-land and a light wave is 3D as you say then what is its length?